# How do i use deduction to choose the return type of function

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, allocation

I have a question regarding the full deduction with functions using C++11 standard. Basically I am ought to make a function that takes a single parameter that should look like a matrix (basically any container) whose elements can again be any container but having in mind that elements of every row do not necessarily need to be the same size. For an example the parameter could be vector of deques, classic C-like matrix, vector of vectors, deques of vectors and so on, you get the point. Having said that. Function itself needs to dynamically alocate (using fragmented and not continual allocation) memory for 2d matrix with same structure and type of elements and then copy all the elements from given matrix into it, and finally return a double pointer which you can use to access the elements of matrix. Having that said, I do not actually know how to use full deduction so that the function actually knows which type is the double pointer that it must return. First thing that crosses my mind is to use something like this:

```
template <typename MatrixType>
auto CreateMatrix (MatrixType M) -> decltype ...
```

Logic behind it is that full deduction would find out what type of double pointer must be returned, but the three dots (...) is where im halted, i dont actually know what to write there.

Ofcourse I could probably do something like this:

```
template <typename MatrixType>
MatrixType** CreateMatrix (MatrixType M)
```

But it doesn't use deduction because call like this:

```
std::vector<std::deque<double>> a = {...};
auto x = CreateMatrix(a);
```

wouldn't work without using `<double>` with the call of the function, so it is not a full "problem solved" it is just a cheap trick.

Memory allocation shouldn't be hard, I think It would be pretty easy to do, but currently I'm stuck here and do not know what to do.

I am grateful for every help!

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want to do. If the function takes a `std::vector<std::deque<double>>` and then internally creates a container of same type then there is no double pointer that could be used to access all element in that vector of deques

Comment: when you say "... 2d matrix with same structure and type of elements and then copy all the elements from given matrix into it" do you mean a plain 2d c array?

Comment: No i don't mean plain 2d c array. If the parameter is the vector of deques, than the function should dynamically allocate memory for  vector of deques, copy all the elements from the given matrix (from the parameter) into the structure that the function made, and then return the double pointer to that same structure that the function made. Sorry if it is hard to explain, trying my best.

Comment: you cannot use a `double**` to access elements in a `std::vector<std::deque<double>>`

Comment: Basically, I want to make this possible, ill write a short code

Comment: it is possible to write a trait that determines the value type from all kinds of types that can be used as matrix. Though, it seems like your issues are elsewhere. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? How would you use the function?

Comment: "I want to make this possible" There is not much you can do about it. `std::deque` does not store elements in contiguous memory. A single pointer cannot be used to access all elements. It wouldnt even work with a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` even though a vectors elements are stored contiguously.

Comment: std::vector<std::deque<double>> V = { {1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8},{9,10} };
auto X = CreateMatrix (V);

And then X could be used with [][] to access the elements

Comment: before tackling the most generic you should try to get one case. Try `std::vector<std::deque<double>>` and use `double**` explicity as return type. You will find that you cannot return a `double**` that would allow to access elements in the vector of deques

Comment: "And then X could be used with [][] to access the elements" this can be done, but not with a `double**` that points to elements of a `std::vector<std::deque<double>>`

Comment: That is what i wanted, sorry if i used wrong terminology

Comment: it is still unclear what you want to do. Both vector and deque already have `operator[]` that you can use. They also can be copied without writing any extra code. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What would be the purpose of the function? It takes a matrix as parameter and returns the same matrix?

Comment: Yes exactly that. It does not do anything, besides being an excercise for me with using generic functions, double pointers and memory allocation.

Comment: but I already tried to explain that you cannot use a double pointer to access elements in a `std:.vector<std::deque<double>>`. Also those containers are made so that you need not do any manual memory allocation. I am afraid you choose the wrong task to train double pointers and memory allocation

Comment: Yes i understood what you wrote, and I thank you for that. I probabbly did not state what i want properly. So just to be sure, you are saying that it is not possible to allocate memory for a 2d structure, whose rows are vectors and whose elements of those rows are deques of doubles, and then return a pointer to the first element of that allocated structure?

Comment: you can return a pointer to the first element but it wont be of much use.

Comment: also you seem to have some misunderstanding concerning allocating memory. You allocate memory for a  `std::vector<std::deque<double>>`  like this:  `std::vector<std::deque<double>> x;`. I can only suggest you again to start with a simpler case, nothing generic but only one case and see how far you get. Once you got that you can still consider to make it work for generic value types or different types of containers

Comment: But would it be possible to copy the elements of the given container into an allocated structure and then return the double pointer? As far as i understood what you wrote, we cannot return a double pointer pointing to elements of vector of deques, but could i allocate memory for M*N matrix that is the type double and then return the double pointer?

Comment: i 100% misswrote what i wanted. Let me rephrase one last time. Given std::vector<std::deque<double>> x; Can the function find out that the elements are actually the type of double and then allocate memory for the structure of that same type (in this case double) and then return double pointer (**double) ?

Comment: "do you mean a plain 2d c array?"  - Yes... you were right, sorry for my bad english..

Comment: `template <typename MatrixType>
auto CreateMatrix (MatrixType M) -> decltype (M[0][0]) ** ` Would this return a double pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not sure if I understood what you want to do. I will concentrate on the actual question: How to infer the value type from a 2D container when the container can be made of standard containers or C arrays?

You can use a type trait. Standard containers have a `value_type` member alias. When an 2d array is passed as pointer `T**` then the value type is `T`. When an array `T[M][N]` is passed by reference then the value type is `T`:

```
template <typename T>
struct value_type { using type = typename T::value_type; };

template <typename T>
struct value_type< T*> { using type = T; };

template <typename T,size_t N>
struct value_type< T[N] > { using type = T;};

template <typename T>
struct value_type2d {
    using type = typename value_type<typename value_type<T>::type>::type;
};
```

As an example I used a function that simple returns the first element:

```
template <typename Matrix>
typename value_type2d<Matrix>::type foo(const Matrix& m) {
    return m[0][0];
}



int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> x{{42,1},{2,3}};
    std::cout << foo(x) << "\n";
    std::vector<std::deque<double>> y{{42,1},{2,3}};
    std::cout << foo(x) << "\n";
    int z[2][2] = {{42,1},{2,3}};
    std::cout << foo(z) << "\n";
    std::vector<std::string> w[2] = {{"42","1"},{"2","3"}};
    std::cout << foo(x) << "\n";
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bY3Y3fhWW)

PS: Yes `decltype( M[0][0] )` is a simpler way to get the value type. Though for example `std::map::operator[]` is not `const` and you should not pass a non const referene when the function does not modify the parameter. And you certainly do not want to copy the whole matrix just to pass it to the function.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for the answer. One more question, wouldnt `decltype( M[0][0] )` return a reference as it is the lvalue? With that, i think i should use something like `typename std::remove_reference<decltype(mat[0][0])>::type **;` do declare a double pointer?

Comment: @casual not all containers have an `operator[]`. You cannot call it on a `const std::map&` and `std::list` doesnt have it at all

Comment: Okay got it, then i should use **M ?

Comment: @casual If thats what you want then use it. I already told you that I am afraid that you choose the wrong task to practice double pointers and/or manual memory allocation. I don't dare to say that you *should* use it